# How to set and get user profile image (vCard) using Xmpp openfire?

Tags: image, xmpp, openfire, profile, vcf-vcard

How to set and get user profile image (vCard) using Xmpp openfire ?

i want create chat app using xmpp openfire ,in this app i want upload user profile image in user registration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Openfire implements [XEP-0054](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0054.html) that describes exactly how users can retrieve and update a vCard. The XEP has detailed instructions. Most client libraries are likely to support this XEP too, which should make it easy for you to make use of that functionality.